# Orthographic Projection Matrix - Triangle in wrong place

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I trying to implement an orthographic projection matrix - currently, all I am trying to do is draw a triangle to the screen, which works fine without the matrix, but as soon as multiply the coordinates by the matrix, the triangle doesn't fit on the page (hard to explain but one point is in the centre, and the other two are far off the page). I've tried it with a different matrix where there are negative coordinates (so the centre of the screen is the origin) and it works fine - am I doing something obviously wrong here? Relevant code is below:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = 
{
     -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(0.0f, 960.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0,0,5),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);

glm::mat4 PVM = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;


GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shader.getShaderID(), "PVM");
```

And then the vertex shader:

```
#version 130    

in vec4 vertexPosition;

uniform mat4 PVM;

out vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vertexPosition * PVM;
    position = vertexPosition;
}
```

I've just included the code I think is relevant.

Comment: Based on what did you determine those values passed to `glm::ortho`? I see, for example, that the "bottom" is larger than the "top" value (the third argument is larger than the fourth). Is that intentional?

Comment: Normally glsl/glm assume a multiplikation of the form M * v. Unless you transposed the matrix somewhere in your code, `PVM * vertexPosition` nicht fix the problem.

Comment: @Nasser, yes this is intentional - this is so the origin is top left, which I believe is standard for 2d games (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @BDL Yes, this does seem to be involving the issue, switching it around along with applying the things of other suggestions does seem to fix the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Well, If you use Orthographics projection with screen resolution, as you probably did. The vertex coordinates become pixel coordinates. So your triangle is only 2pixels wide and half of it is offscreen.

So try to make it a bit bigger.

Comment: Along with the other suggestions, yes this does seem to help solve the problem - I originally thought that the triangle's coordiantes would be multiplied by the matrix, transforming them into the screen coordiantes, but  it seems I have misunderstood. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: @Quimby: Actually, not half of the triangle is offscreen, but all of it. It lies completely behind the far plane.

Comment: @derhass Yea, you are right, I checked only direction of the camera, not the distance.